# In the VIM scripting language, is there a builtin for jump to NERDTree window?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I know there's NERDTree and NERDTreeToggle,

however the function I want is:

if there is not a NERDTree window, pop one up
if there already is one, switch to the NERDTree window

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the NERDTree command. It seems to do this for you unless I'm missing something you want. You can use custom and inbuilt commands straight in vimscript. Eg.

```
function NerdyFoo()
    echo "FooBar"
    NERDTree
    echo "Wibblybits"
endfun

:call NerdyFoo()
```

Comment: :NERDTree
... move up/down, open a directory
... open a file 
:NERDTree
// what we see is a re-opening, the previous directory is closed